# Does Saitama know whats going on around him?

Tags: one-punch-man

Does Saitama know whats going on around him. Like people ignoring him or how people or heroes treat him badly or make fun of him and things like that or is he just an airhead after getting his powers?

Answer (score 3):

Saitama does know that people around him usually treats him badly or coldly, and he really cares about it: that's why he joins the Hero Association and tries to become a hero. In the first few episodes, he cares about how people view him, but in later episodes, he just starts to ignore them( tries his best). For more information, visit the link below.

http://onepunchman.wikia.com/wiki/Saitama

Comment: Sometimes he just ignores them.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: You don't think so? What do you mean?

Comment: Remember the part, where Genos tries to hide the letters from Saitama, that people sent to him saying you are evil

Comment: And also the part where Genoa tries to cheer Saitama up, when Saitama get's know about how people view him.

Comment: Yeah, and he just ignores them.

Comment: He tries his best to ignore them, so that it won't stress him out

Comment: In first few episodes in the anime, he actually cares about how people view him. But later, he tries to ignore them

Comment: Well I guess you're right, but you should atleast put in your answer that he tries to ignore them. Also +1 for your answer.

Comment: I just did that, right now

Comment: Anyways, thx for your feedback